# jQuery autocomplete widget source - where are the arguments coming from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm studying the [autocomplete widget source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-9-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js) to try and help with a widget I'm building. [This line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-9-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L546) makes no sense to me:

```
_value: function() {
  return this.valueMethod.apply( this.element, arguments );
},
```

`valueMethod` [is defined as](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-9-stable/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L60):

```
this.valueMethod = this.element[ this.element.is( "input,textarea" ) ? "val" : "text" ];
```

So where does the `arguments` parameter come from? As I understand it, javascript has functional scope, so there are no `arguments` to pass.

I'm confused, if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `arguments` parameter is something that will always automatically be defined inside a new function in javascript even if you don't explicitly define any. So `apply` is assuming valueMethod is a function and passing along those arguments. Further, you can assume `this.element[ this.element.is( "input,textarea" ) ? "val" : "text" ];` will return a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> [`arguments` is] an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.
>   The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all functions; arguments as a property of `Function` can no longer be used.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

In other words, it is - for *most* intents and purposes - an array containing the arguments passed to the function which is useful for a number of reason... especially when creating a method or function that accepts a variable number of arguments. In this case, all the arguments are just being passed along to another method, `this.valueMethod`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found it difficult to chose between yours and Chris' answer, as they're both really helpful but also too close to call. He answered just before you so that's why I gave his answer the tick, but I'm really grateful for your input.